# Creating Table of Values (Exponential Equation)

Tags: word-problem

So I have these equations and is wondering if I'm doing this correctly. So what I have is 'y = 1000(1.037)^2t'. So what I'm doing to get the value is basically multiplying 1.037 to the 2nd power and multiplying that with 1000. Is this correct or do I have to do something different?

What I thought of: Should I change the equation so it goes like 'y = 1000(1.037)^2/t or t/2?

Textbook Question: 'An investment of $1,000 earns 3.7% interest and is compounded semi-annually'. <--- Just a reference for those of you guys that need it.

Comment: You do not seem to have included $t$ in your description of how you do your calculation.  As for the rest, it rather depends on whether the $3.7\%$ is a semi-annual rate, double the semi-annual rate, the annual effective rate, or the confusingly titled continuously compounding rate.

Comment: @Henry I don't know either to be honest. I added that because it increases semi-annually. So should I change it to y = 1000(1.037)^t/2? And also another reason being is we always add variables as an exponent. So I don't know I'm new to this type of thing.

Comment: @Henry Any other ideas?